# dart, is it possible to execute code on library load?

Tags: dart

I have a library in my lib/sndbx.dart file:

```dart
library sndbx;

bool foo(){
  print('hey hey!');
  return true;
}

bool bar = foo();
```

and I have a main in my bin/sndbx_cmd.dart:

```dart
import 'package:sndbx_cmd/sndbx.dart';

void main() {
  print("Hello, World!");
}
```

but I don't see "hey hey!" printed to the commandline, how come when the library gets loaded it doesn't define the top level bool variable `bar`?

I see that if I get the `bar` value:

```dart
import 'package:sndbx_cmd/sndbx.dart';

void main() {
  print("Hello, World!");
  print(bar);
  print(bar);
}
```

I get:

```dart
Hello World!
hey hey!
true
true
```

so why does it only call `foo` once? what if I changed it to:

```dart
library sndbx;

bool called = false;

bool foo(){
  print('hey hey!');
  return called = !called;
}

bool bar = foo();
```

because `bar` doesn't get defined on project load it feels like it acts as a getter but it only gets the value on the first call and the value is cached there after where I might expect it to keep calling `foo` every time I access it since that's what it does on the first access, as opposed to being defined when the library is initially loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be called every time you read it you actually have it to make a getter.

`bar` is lazy evaluated (on first access).

As far as I know there is no way to execute code on library load. You have to invoke it from `main()` (or a method called form `main()` of course).

Comment: yeh that's pretty much what I assumed I was just wondering if there was a reason it was evaluated on first access rather than "before first access" as I dont see a reason why it couldnt be evaluated before hand.

Comment: If you don't access the code execution would be redundant. This is a performance optimization.

Comment: Description of when this was introduced. http://news.dartlang.org/2012/02/static-variables-no-longer-have-to-be.html

Comment: Not just a performance optimization, also a predictability improvement. Executing code can have side effects. In Dart it is very predictable when initializers of a  top-level/static variable is executed - when you first access it. All code executed in a program derives from the initial "main" call. If initializers were executed when the library was loaded (before calling main), the runtime would have to pick an initialization order, and it would have to have a way to handle it if the initializers throw (e.g., a cyclic reference list 'final x = x;').

Comment: what about polymer dart, could anyone explain how it registers its annotations `@CustomTag('my-tag')` when a library is loaded? as I read this in the src: 

/// Metadata used to label static or top-level methods that are called
/// automatically when loading the library of a custom element.
const initMethod = const InitMethodAnnotation();

Comment: Polymer has a custom main (if you don't provide your own) and the transformer replaces the `@CustomTag` annotations with generated code that calls the element initialization.